# Flutter Navigation showing route as /

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator, flutter-navigation

I have a card with PopupMenuButton that I can tap to perform the 'copy' action. I can also perform the same action from the card details page. The problem I have is to get back to the home page I have to cater for both paths. So if the action is performed from the details page, I need to pop twice to go back to the home page.

> Action from the home page:
>
> Home > add card page
>
> - navigator.pop() takes me back to home page
>
> Action from the details page:
>
> home > card details page > add card page
>
> - Having to pop twice here.

I know I have to do the `pop` atleast once and then I used the `popUntil` to check the current state of the route. For some reason, it is always popping twice.

After debugging, its showing current route as `/`

```
  void _changeRoute(String newRouteName) {
    bool isNewRoute = false;

    // Pop once
    Navigator.pop(context); // after this I should be on home page for the first path

    Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
      print('Current route is ${route.settings.name}');

      if (route.settings.name == newRouteName) { // but this is showing current route as /
        isNewRoute = true;
      }
      return true;
    });

    print('is home page: $isNewRoute');

    if (!isNewRoute) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this working.

My problem was that in my Main App, I had specified the `home` property on `MaterialApp`. According to the documentation, if the `home` property is specified, it takes the route `/`. So my home page is `/` and I had it defined as `/home` in my routes and this was being overridden by `/`.